# build webrtc with is_debug=true, got link error in c++ proj use webrtc, undefined reference to std::__cxx11::basic_string

Tags: debugging, webrtc

when I add use_debug=true into gn args, I build my proj with libwebrtc.a got link error :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ray7F.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ec70b.png)
my command for build webrtc is below :

```
args="rtc_use_h264=true"
args="$args use_ghash=false"
args="$args use_custom_libcxx=false"
args="$args clang_use_chrome_plugins=false"
args="$args rtc_enable_protobuf=false"
args="$args use_rtti=true"
args="$args target_os=\"linux\" target_cpu=\"x64\""
args="$args is_component_build=false"
args="$args symbol_level=1"
args="$args rtc_include_tests=false"
args="$args rtc_build_examples=false"
args="$args is_debug=true"

gn gen out/Release-clang --args="$args"

ninja -C out/Release-clang
```

my proj's cmake file is below:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)

project(test)
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER "clang++")
add_definitions( -DWEBRTC_POSIX=1 )
add_definitions( -DWEBRTC_USE_H264=1 )

set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE Debug)
 
if(CMAKE_COMPILER_IS_GNUCXX)
    add_compile_options(-std=c++17)
    add_compile_options(-fPIC) 
    # add_compile_options(-O2)
    add_compile_options(-stdlib=libstdc++) 
    add_compile_options(-g) 
endif(CMAKE_COMPILER_IS_GNUCXX)

aux_source_directory("./src" SRC_LIST)
  
include_directories("../include/" ) 
include_directories("../include/third_party/abseil-cpp" ) 
 
link_directories("${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/../lib/") 
message(${SRC_LIST})
 
SET(LIBS webrtc pthread stdc++)
 
ADD_EXECUTABLE(test "./src/main" ${SRC_LIST})

target_link_libraries(test ${LIBS})
```

the branch of webrtc I used is 6261

I'm awared, all is right when I not use is_debug=true to build webrtc

Comment: Please post the error as a text, and not a screenshot.